# Enviar props de un componente a otro que está en un layout en React.js

Tags: reactjs, component

Realmente no sé si esto sea posible, espero que sí.

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente: Tengo un layout, el cual tiene el típico footer y header, pero también tengo uno llamado PageHeading, el cual tiene un título, como también breadcrums.

[image: Este es el componente PageHeading]

Entonces lo que quisiera hacer es poder enviar información a este componente en las páginas en donde lo vaya a utilizar.

Por ejemplo en este caso tengo el siguiente componente que es una vista:

```
    const Tournament = () => (
        <div class="row">
            <div className="col-md-8">
    <TournamentLive title="Transmisión del torneo" frameUrl="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=xxx" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <TournamentInformation />
                <Standings />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
export default Tournament;
```

Por otra parte, el componente del PageHeading es este:

```
const PageHeading = () => (
    <div className="page-heading page-heading--horizontal effect-duotone effect-duotone--primary">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col align-self-start">
                        <h1 className="page-heading__title">Torneo <span className="highlight">#1</span></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col align-self-end">
                        <ol className="page-heading__breadcrumb breadcrumb font-italic">
                            <li className="breadcrumb-item"><a href="_esports_index.html">Directorio</a></li>
                            <li className="breadcrumb-item"><a href="_football_features-shortcodes.html">League of Legends</a></li>
                            <li className="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Torneo #1</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
);
```

El layout que tengo es el siguiente:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Header />
    <PageHeading  />
    <section className="section--bg1">
        <div className="site-content">
          <div className="container">
          {children}
          </div>
          </div>
          </section>
    <Footer />
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

El problema es que el **PageHeading** no lo puedo poner individualmente por componente ya que si lo hago, quedará dentro de un **container** y no fuera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces me gustaría que me den sugerencias para poder resolver esto. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Que clase de información le quieres enviar? Cambiarle el titulo, por ejemplo?

Comment: Correcto, el titulo @FedericoMadoery

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacer lo siguiente, es la forma mas simple:

```
const PageHeading = ({tittle}) => (
    <div className="page-heading page-heading--horizontal effect-duotone effect-duotone--primary">
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col align-self-start">
                    <h1 className="page-heading__title">{tittle}</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="col align-self-end">
                    <ol className="page-heading__breadcrumb breadcrumb font-italic">
                        <li className="breadcrumb-item"><a href="_esports_index.html">Directorio</a></li>
                        <li className="breadcrumb-item"><a href="_football_features-shortcodes.html">League of
                            Legends</a></li>
                        <li className="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Torneo #1</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);


const Layout = ({children}) => {
    // Declaración de una variable de estado que llamaremos "tittle" y su 'setter',
    // con un valor por defecto que trae el children.headerTittle o "defaulTittle"
    // Aqui puede usar el setter para cambiar, sino no haria falta hacer el setter propiamente dicho
     const [tittle, setTittle] = useState( children.headerTittle || 'defaulTittle');

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Header/>
            <PageHeading tittle={tittle}/>
            <section className="section--bg1">
                <div className="site-content">
                    <div className="container">
                        {children}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <Footer/>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

---

> PD: También podes caer en casos mas complejos como clonar el elemento
>   *children* y agregarla la función para cambiar el valor del titulo, lo cual requiere un refactor un poco mayor del código, ya que el clonado
>   puede generar comportamientos extraños con esta estructura si lo
>   implementas así sin mas